# check user have liked msg or not from list of messages

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views, backend

suppose

```
class Msg(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,...)
    channelname = models.CharField(...)
```

Now my queryset is

```
queryset = Msg.objects.filter(channelname='home')
```

What should i do after this to get somelike

```
[{id:xyz,liked=true},{id:tuv,liked=true},{id:abc,liked:false}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate an [`Exists()` subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) using the [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) of your many to many field:

```py
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


liked_subquery = Msg.likes.through.objects.filter(
    msg=OuterRef('pk'),  # Filter for outer queries Msg instance
    user=some_user_instance  # Filter for user whose like we are checking for
)
queryset = Msg.objects.filter(
    channelname='home'
).annotate(
    liked=Exists(liked_subquery)
).values('id', 'liked')

print(list(queryset))
```

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: @RoyalBosS what do you mean? Did you get an error? Please see the edit does that loop at the end print what you want?

Comment: read the question again

Comment: @RoyalBosS you say it doesn't work _just_ because the output is not a dictionary (Honestly that is quite easy to do yourself)? I though the question focused on finding whether a user liked a `Msg` or not, check the edit...